# Vim: insert the same characters across multiple lines

Tags: vim

Sometimes I want to edit a certain visual block of text across multiple lines.

For example, I would take a text that looks like this:

```
name
comment
phone
email
```

And make it look like this

```
vendor_name
vendor_comment
vendor_phone
vendor_email
```

Currently the way I would do it now is...

1. Select all 4 row lines of a block by pressing <kbd>V</kbd> and then <kbd>j</kbd> four times.
2. Indent with <kbd>></kbd>.
3. Go back one letter with <kbd>h</kbd>.
4. Go to block visual mode with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>.
5. Select down four rows by pressing <kbd>j</kbd> four times. At this point you have selected a 4x1 visual blocks of whitespace (four rows and one column).
6. Press <kbd>C</kbd>. Notice this pretty much indented to the left by one column.
7. Type out a `" vendor_"` without the quote. Notice the extra space we had to put back.
8. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd>. This is one of the very few times I use <kbd>Esc</kbd> to get out of insert mode. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> would only edit the first line.
9. Repeat step 1.
10. Indent the other way with <kbd><</kbd>.

I don't need to indent if there is at least one column of whitespace before the words. I wouldn't need the whitespace if I didn't have to clear the visual block with <kbd>c</kbd>.

But if I have to clear, then is there a way to do what I performed above without creating the needed whitespace with indentation?

Also why does editing multiple lines at once only work by exiting out of insert mode with <kbd>Esc</kbd> over <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>?

---

Here is a more complicated example:

```
name    = models.CharField( max_length = 135 )
comment = models.TextField( blank = True )
phone   = models.CharField( max_length = 135, blank = True )
email   = models.EmailField( blank = True )
```

to

```
name    = models.whatever.CharField( max_length = 135 )
comment = models.whatever.TextField( blank = True )
phone   = models.whatever.CharField( max_length = 135, blank = True )
email   = models.whatever.EmailField( blank = True )
```

In this example I would perform the vertical visual block over the `.`, and then reinsert it back during insert mode, i.e., type `.whatever.`. Hopefully now you can see the drawback to this method. I am limited to only selecting a column of text **that are all the same in a vertical position**.

Comment: Better way: ":%s/^/vendor_/"

Comment: Thanks for the response. That works if I only want to append a word to every line. But the method I use can be done at any position. Let me add another my example with a more complicated example.

Comment: Then highlight the lines you want to change with shift-V, and type an appropriate search and replace command - in the second example, `:s/models\./\0whatever./`

Comment: Many ways to achieve the above. To fully answer all parts of question then part 1) either regex or visual mode I edit esc works nicely as offered in answers (I prefer visual selection in GVIM). For part 2), macro is perhaps easiest as offered by Brian Neal. The best resource I know of for all these kinds of "how tos" is Practical Vim by Drew Neil. Excellent quick read and light weight reference whenever you forget a formula. Hope this recommendation helps someone, it will be well worth the effort for many vim users.

Comment: @Paul: And if you’re [counting keystrokes](http://www.vimgolf.com/), you could replace `\0` with `&`.

Answer (score 1266, accepted):

1. Move the cursor to the `n` in `name`.
2. Enter visual block mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>).
3. Press <kbd>j</kbd> three times (or <kbd>3j</kbd>) to jump down by 3 lines; <kbd>G</kbd> (capital g) to jump to the last line
4. Press <kbd>`I`</kbd> (capital i).
5. Type in `vendor_`. Note: It will only update the screen in the ***first*** line - until <kbd>Esc</kbd> is pressed (6.), at which point all lines will be updated.
6. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

[image: mini-screencast demonstrating the method]

An uppercase `I` must be used rather than a lowercase `i`, because the lowercase `i` is interpreted as the start of a [text object](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#text-objects), which is rather useful on its own, e.g. for selecting inside a tag block ([`it`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#it)):

[image: mini-screencast showing the usefulness of the 'it' text object]

Comment: Whoa, I didn't know `I` worked in visual block. Obviously I tried `i` before but it beeped on me, so I used `c` since then... and had the described limitation. Thanks for the answer! :-)

Comment: I couldn't get this to work in Windows (since CTRL+V is mapped for clipboard paste). But Vim has also mapped this to **Ctrl+Q** for the Windows version.

Comment: @Ven: Vim’s not actually busy during that time—it’s just waiting for you to press another key, and eventually times out. Two experiments for you: first, try pressing escape and then immediately pressing another key, like `j` or `^L`. You should see that Vim wasn’t busy after all; it was just waiting. Second, try changing [`'timeout'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27timeout%27) to a lower value, like `80` (rather than the default `1000`) and observe that it times out more quickly.

Comment: @Ven: If you’re attentive enough, you’ll catch the timeout occurring in a few different places, not just here. But if the delay in updates after pressing escape annoys you, you should try switching to a GUI version of Vim rather than running it in a terminal emulator. When running in a terminal emulator, Vim has to interpret various escape sequences, and some of those may require a timeout; but when using a GUI, Vim knows exactly what you did, and can eliminate some of those timeouts.

Comment: @icktoofay pressing j instantly after escape didn't do anything more (it just did like if I waited the 1s timeout then pressed `j`). Also, doesn't using a GUI version defeat the purpose of using vim :P ?

Comment: @Ven: Well, the `<Esc>j` experiment [works on my machine](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-works-on-my-machine-certification-program/). As for the use of the GUI version, no, I don’t think it defeats the purpose of using Vim. I find Vim useful in part because it is quick to make changes, particularly repetitive ones, and navigate. Vim is also useful because it can be used within a terminal, but that is not my primary purpose for using it. Using the GUI gives me other advantages, like being able to use more colors (my terminal emulator is crippled and supports only 16 colors).

Comment: @icktoofay sorry, "defeating the purpose" was a joke ;-). I just reduced the timeoutlen to 10 and am happy with that.

Comment: @icktoofay It looks like the variable you mean to set is `timeoutlen` not `timeout`.

Comment: @icktoofay Hi, this example shows how to insert test in to left side of the existing test. How can I do the same to the right side of the existing text ? I have a number sequence.

Comment: @ANjaNA: If where you want to insert is all in the same column (e.g. if the numbers are all the same length), you can use the same technique except pressing `A` rather than `I`, which will insert after the selected block rather than before. If your lines are different lengths, though, that won’t work; I like to use a substitution matching the end of each line for that, e.g. selecting some lines and using `:s/$/inserted/`.

Comment: @Micha: I answered that in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549729/in-vim-how-do-i-effectively-insert-the-same-characters-across-multiple-lines/9549765?noredirect=1#comment48730366_9549765).

Comment: I had to press down arrow after pressing esc to get this to work

Comment: Like @Arnestig said, `ctrl`+`q` also works for Mac to enter visual block mode if `ctrl`+`v` is mapped to something else.

Comment: @GeoSword I too can only get it to work by pressing escape followed by an arrow key. Strange. Pressing escape any number of times doesn't do anything. Pressing escape followed by any other key behaves as if escape entered NORMAL mode then hit the said key (so esc+j will move one line down, then place me back into INSERT, instead of writing repeating the desired input).

Comment: @GeoSword EDIT: It works when running with `vim -u NONE`. Something made its way into my .vimrc and broke the `<esc>` behavior. Did you ever find what caused your problem?

Comment: Okay! Fixed my escape key, in case anyone stumbles, I had things like `map ^[h <a-h>` inside my vimrc, and disabling all those makes Vim (or Neovim) not wait for ey presses after pressing escape.

Comment: One tip for the readers! Put `inoremap <c-c> <esc>` in your vimrc so you can press ctrl+c instead of escape to end the multi-line editing.

Comment: This works perfectly for inserting text, but it doesn't seem to work for deleting text, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This does not answer why editing multiple lines at once only work by exiting out of insert mode with `Esc` over `Ctrl` `c`.

Comment: What do you do if it literally just doesn't work?

Comment: Needed to use `c` in step 4 in windows, instead of `I`

Comment: Thank you very much for the GIF, it worked for me on mac, posted my solution in https://github.com/cniackz/public/wiki/How-to-replace-%60pick%60-by-%60s%60-in-the-commit-on-%60vi%60

Answer (score 116):

Another approach is to use the <kbd>.</kbd> (`dot`) command in combination with <kbd>i</kbd>.

1. Move the cursor where you want to start
2. Press <kbd>i</kbd>
3. Type in the prefix you want (e.g. `vendor_`)
4. Press <kbd>esc</kbd>.
5. Press <kbd>j</kbd> to go down a line
6. Type <kbd>.</kbd> to repeat the last edit, automatically inserting the prefix again
7. Alternate quickly between <kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>.</kbd>

I find this technique is often faster than the visual block mode for small numbers of additions and has the added benefit that if you don't need to insert the text on every single line in a range you can easily skip them by pressing extra <kbd>j</kbd>'s.

Note that for large number of contiguous additions, the block approach or macro will likely be superior.

Comment: I prefer this for only a few lines. Much easier to execute IMO.

Comment: After you type in the prefix you want, don't you then need to press escape key?

Comment: @iamnotsam, if you are in insert mode, then yes you need to press Esc before moving to the next line. Otherwise pressing "." will simply insert a period.

Comment: this is amazing. also works with deleting things.

Answer (score 82):

1. Select the lines you want to modify using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>.
2. Press:

   - <kbd>I</kbd>: Insert before what's selected.
   - <kbd>A</kbd>: Append after what's selected.
   - <kbd>c</kbd>: Replace what's selected.
3. Type the new text.
4. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to apply the changes to all selected lines.

Comment: Excellent! I'd just highlight the final step `Esc` for VIM noobs like myself - it took me a while to figure out that the changes get propagated "later"!

Comment: Nice, didn't know about "A" and "C" options too.

Comment: Why doesn't this work for `v`? I can do it with `Ctrl+V --> A`, but doing `v` to select the text doesn't work -- `A` only appends to that line. Aren't they both selection? Also, very strange -- `A` only appends to the end of the line IF I extend the visual block to the end of the line; otherwise it appends wherever the visual block ends for each line. It's like it doesn't recognize a difference between `a` and `A`.

Comment: I needed to use `c` instead of `C`, but it worked perfectly fine. Thank you

Answer (score 43):

I would use a macro to record my actions and would then repeat it.

1. Put your cursor on the first letter in *name*.
2. Hit <kbd>qq</kbd> to start recording into the q buffer.
3. Hit <kbd>i</kbd> to go into insert mode, type *vector_*, and then hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> to leave insert mode.
4. Now hit <kbd>0</kbd> to go back to the beginning of the line.
5. Now hit <kbd>j</kbd> to go down.
6. Now hit <kbd>q</kbd> again to stop recording.

You now have a nice macro.

Type <kbd>3@q</kbd> to execute your macro three times to do the rest of the lines.

Comment: Is "q" special (for "quick macro"?)?

Comment: How can the macro be made persistent (working across several sessions)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Vim has a feature called sessions that will persist buffers (and a lot of other things) that you can look into.

Comment: From one Peter to another, great answer!

Answer (score 35):

```
:%s/^/vendor_/
```

or am I missing something?

Comment: You're missing the fact that it's likely a subtext in a file with many other lines on which the `vender_` prefix is unwanted.

Comment: @dan If only a subtext is needed, you can limit the search to a set of line numbers, eg `1,4s/^/vendor_/`

Comment: @BradKoch Interesting. I was not aware of the line number constraints, thanks for that.

Comment: it is interesting, but what's more practical is to visually block select with `V` and type `:`. It will prefix the ed expression with `:'<,'>` which make the ed apply only to the selection with `:'<,'>s/^/vendor_/`

Comment: if you highlight matches like I do you may need to run `:noh` after.

Answer (score 19):

**Updated January 2016**

*Whilst the accepted answer is a great solution, this is actually slightly fewer keystrokes, and scales better - based in principle on the accepted answer.*

1. Move the cursor to the `n` in `name`.
2. Enter visual block mode (<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>).
3. Press <kbd>3j</kbd>
4. Press <kbd>`I`</kbd>.
5. Type in `vendor_`.
6. Press <kbd>esc</kbd>.

[image: visual illustration]

Note, this has fewer keystrokes than the accepted answer provided (compare Step 3). We just count the number of j actions to perform.

If you have line numbers enabled (as illustrated above), and know the line number you wish to move to, then step 3 can be changed to #<kbd>G</kbd> where # is the wanted line number.

In our example above, this would be <kbd>4G</kbd>. However when dealing with just a few line numbers an explicit count works well.

Answer (score 18):

An alternative that can be more flexible:

Example: To enter the text XYZ at the beginning of the line

```
:%norm IXYZ
```

What's happening here?

- `%` == Execute on every line
- `norm` == Execute the following keys in normal mode (short for `normal`)
- `I` == Insert at beginning of line
- `XYZ` == The text you want to enter

Then you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and it executes.

Specific to your request:

```
:%norm Ivendor_
```

You can also choose a particular range:

```
:2,4norm Ivendor_
```

Or execute over a selected visual range:

```
:'<,'>norm Ivendor_
```

Or execute for each line that matches a 'target' regex:

```
:%g/target/norm Ivendor_
```

Comment: is it possible to send key sequences like <Esc> while in insert mode (norm Iabc<ESC>) in order to do more interesting stuff?

Comment: @batbrat I just figured this out! You can hit `ctrl-v ctrl-[` to insert an "escaped Esc", which pulls you back to "normal mode" for the purpose of your normal command.

I just tested this with `'<,'>norm Iaa^[ysiw"`, where `^[` is the escaped Esc.

Comment: The `:%mode` approach is really valuable to know. I'm glad I stumbled upon this answer!

Answer (score 10):

You might also have a use case where you want to delete a block of text and replace it.

Like this

```
Hello World

Hello World
```

To

```
Hello Cool

Hello Cool
```

You can just visual block select "World" in both lines.

Type <kbd>c</kbd> for change - now you will be in insert mode.

Insert the stuff you want and hit escape.

Both get reflected vertically. It works just like 'I', except that it replaces the block with the new text instead of inserting it.

Answer (score 10):

I wanted to comment out a **lot of lines** in some config file on a server that only had vi (no nano), so visual method was cumbersome as well 
Here's how i did that.

1. Open file `vi file`
2. Display line numbers `:set number!` or `:set number`
3. Then use the line numbers to replace start-of-line with "#", how?

`:35,77s/^/#/`

Note: the numbers are inclusive, lines from 35 to 77, both included will be modified.

To uncomment/undo that, simply use `:35,77s/^#//`

If you want to add a text word as a comment after every line of code, you can also use:

`:35,77s/$/#test/` (for languages like Python)

`:35,77s/;$/;\/\/test/` (for languages like Java)

credits/references:

1. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84929/uncommenting-multiple-lines-of-code-specified-by-line-numbers-using-vi-or-vim
2. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120615/how-to-comment-multiple-lines-at-once

Comment: This was the perfect solution for me as I'm often only using vim-tiny.

Answer (score 7):

Suppose you have this file:

```
something

name
comment
phone
email

something else
and more ...
```

You want to add "vendor_" in front of "name", "comment", "phone", and "email", *regardless of where they appear in the file*.

```
:%s/\<\(name\|comment\|phone\|email\)\>/vendor_\1/gc
```

The `c` flag will prompt you for confirmation. You can drop that if you don't want the prompt.

Answer (score 5):

```
Use Ctrl+V to enter visual block mode
Move Up/Down to select the columns of text in the lines you want to comment.
Then hit Shift+i and type the text you want to insert.
Then hit Esc, wait 1 second and the inserted text will appear on every line
```

Comment: does this method work for all versions of vim or require any vim plugins? the reason why i ask is b/c it sometimes works on some machines, but sometimes does not. i can't figure out the difference. vim that comes with git on windows - i can't get it working. on some ubuntu and centos linux machines, i can't get it working. i have had success in a few rare cases, but i could not reproduce the success. it's a mystery.  nothing seems to happen after i hit ESC.

Comment: oddly, it DOES work for me now. nothing has changed, except maybe the stars :)

while looking for solution to my issue, i did find something at this page though that mentions something to look for in vim 

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Inserting_text_in_multiple_lines

    In Vim, check that you have the blockwise-operators feature (I, A, and more) by entering the :version command. The output should include +visualextra.

Comment: I meant to add a comment in general, not to your answer. Most of these answers say the same thing but using different words. Mine had something different to offer and included a link.

Answer (score 4):

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + v to go to visual block mode
2. Select the lines using the up and down arrow
3. Enter lowercase <kbd>3i</kbd> (press *lowercase* <kbd>I</kbd> three times)
4. <kbd>I</kbd> (press capital <kbd>I</kbd>. That will take you into insert mode.)
5. Write the text you want to add
6. <kbd>Esc</kbd>
7. Press the down arrow

Answer (score 1):

I came here to paste in many lines an already copied string. When copy with `y` we can paste, in the INSERT MODE, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> and right after press <kbd>''</kbd>. This will have the same result as being in NORMAL MODE and press <kbd>p</kbd>. This is called paste from registry.

Suppose the following text in the buffer:

```
vendor_something

text
to_receive
the_paste
pattern
```

Then we can put the cursor pointing to v in vendor_ and press <kbd>v</kbd>, move to right using <kbd>l</kbd> until select the underscore symbol we want to paste in the text bellow. After that, we can point the cursor at the beginning of "text" (two lines bellow vendor_something) and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>. Then `I` to go into INSERT MODE where we press `3j` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> <kbd>''</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd>. The result of this sequence will be:

```
vendor_something

vendor_text
vendor_to_receive
vendor_the_paste
vendor_pattern
```

Answer (score 1):

:.,+3s/^/vendor_/

Another example, I needed to just add two spaces to a block of 125 lines, so I used  (with cursor positioned at the beginning of the first line of the block):

:.,+125s/^/  /

Worked great.

Answer (score 1):

If the change is required in the entire file,

```
:1,$s/^/vendor_/
```

If the change is required for only a few lines,

Go to the first line where change is required, and either give the command

```
:.,ns/^/vendor_/
```

Substitute n with the line number of the last line in the block.

Or,

```
:.,+ns/^/vendor_/
```

Substitute n with number of lines minus 1 in which the change is required.