# prepend to visual block not working in vim

Tags: linux, vim, block

I'm really fond of this idea of using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd> in windows) to modify a visual block.  The technique is explained here: [In Vim how do I effectively insert the same characters across multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549729/in-vim-how-do-i-effectively-insert-the-same-characters-across-multiple-lines)

For some reason, this is not working for me in VIM 7.2.411.

I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>, it says visual block, and I press <kbd>J</kbd> several times to expand my selection.  Then I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd> to insert, place my text, and when I press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, it has only modified the top line of the selection.  I've had a hard time figuring out why this isn't working on my linux box.  The same technique works great for gvim in windows.

What might be preventing this from working, or what should I try differently?

Comment: What happens if you start with `vim --noplugin`? And with `vim -u NONE -N`?

Comment: With --noplugin there is no change.  With vim -u NONE -N my syntax highlighting is gone but the visual-block technique still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: 1. Update Vim to a newer version. 2. When you compare Vim on different platforms, make sure both are the same version and both have the same settings. 3. Did you import your Windows config wholesale? 4. Could you show us your configuration?

Comment: My .vimrc file in linux is: set number, set hlsearch, set ai, set tabstop=4

Comment: Had the same problem. I normally use shift-v to select line, and never Ctrl-v for select block. This seems to only work on select block, which is where I was going wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source of the problem was lack of compiled support (thanks to my shared hosting provider).  For others who are having a similar problem, check vim for the +visualextra option.  You can check from normal mode with:

```
:echo has('visualextra')
```

It will return a "1" if it does.  Otherwise you can look using:

```
:version
```

Or by invoking the --version option from the commandline:

```
vim --version | grep visualextra
```

Comment: I have visualextra and this problem at the same time?

Comment: @LittleBigBot Follow the comment thread under my question and see if that helps.

Answer (score 3):

It may be as simple as not having the right package installed. Visual block mode is not included in `vim-minimal` which is often the default version of vi. If you do this:

```
rpm -qa | grep vim
```

and you see `vim-minimal` but not `vim-enhanced`, then you have to install `vim-enhanced`. That will get you visual block mode as well as many other additional features.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior you describe with gvim on windows is quite unexpected.  I would expect the inserted text to appear only before the first line.  If you do want to insert a string before all the lines of the currently selected visual block, the natural thing to do is:

```
:s/^/inserted text
```

(Note that when you type `:`, vim will automatically set the addresses with `:'<,'>`, so the actual command will be `:'<,'>s/^/inserted text`)

Comment: I should have mentioned that the problem child was vim on linux with my shared hosting provider.