# Inserting text in multiple lines in vim, not working for std::

Tags: vim

I was practicing inserting text in multiple lines in vim, as given in [this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Inserting_text_in_multiple_lines) tutorial and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9549765/1928133) SO answer as well.

But this technique doesn't seem to work if the text to be inserted is something like "std::" or even "std:" The colon at the end seems to mess up something.

For a code like

```
cout << "Hello World" << endl;
cout << "Yo Yo!" << endl;
```

I take my cursor to the first line, at 'c', press, 'Ctrl+V' to enter Visual Block mode. Then I press 'j' to select the next line as well. Then I press 'I' to enter the special insert mode and then I enter the text I want to insert. Then I press 'Esc'

For any simple text such as 'try_',

it gives

```
try_cout << "Hello World" << endl;
try_cout << "Yo Yo!" << endl;
```

But if my text is something like 'std::'

it just gives

```
std::cout << "Hello World" << endl;
cout << "Yo Yo!" << endl;
```

**It just ends up inserting text on the first line, leaving the others intact.**

Please guide.

Comment: You forgot to tell us what happens when you type `std::` and to describe what you do.

Comment: @romainl Actually sir! I did mention that it just ends up inserting text on the first line when I type 'std::' and does not replicate the action for all lines. 

I feel describing what I do is redundant. I have provided two links which give the same set of steps that I have replicated.

Though, I will edit to *explicitly* note these two

Comment: See? Your question isa lot better, now. Do you have some autocompletion plugin?

Comment: @romainl No. No plugins at all. Whatever comes in utopic package

Comment: @romainl Ubuntu 14.10

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by vim's cindent setting. When you type `std:`, vim assumes you are creating a label named "std" and reduces its indentation to 0. For some reason, this is messing with the visual block insert. Enter `:set nocindent` to temporarily get the behavior you desire. I'm not sure if this can be fixed in a more permanent fashion, but you probably don't do this very often.