# insert a '\' in the 81st column across multiple lines (potentially less than 80 characters long) in vim?

Tags: vim

*Note: **Not** a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549729/in-vim-how-do-i-effectively-insert-the-same-characters-across-multiple-lines)*

I've been writing a lot of C/C++ preprocessor macros lately, and my groups coding style wants me to put a '\' in the 81st column of each line in a multi-line macro.  For instance,

```
#define hello_world_macro(foo, bar)                                           \
if(foo) {                                                                     \
  std::cout << bar << std::endl;                                              \
}                                                                             \
```

For complicated cases, I find it easiest to write out a specific case of the macro, make sure it compiles, then go through and change the specific case into the macro case.  The problem is that adding '\' in the right column for, e.g., 100+ lines is *really* tedious, and `C-v` won't work because the lines aren't 80 characters long when I go to add the '\'s.  What's the easiest way to do this in vim?

Comment: I like [clang-format](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) (Assuming it can handle your style) it will format your macros like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `virtualedit` option:

```
:set ve=all
```

Then you can move your cursor anywhere after the end of the line, with this command for example: `81|`; then you just have to use `Ctrl-V` + up/down arrows, and after this : `r\` to add some backslashes on each line.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  Did not know about `virutaledit`

Comment: If you have [unimpaired.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) installed, use `cov` to toggle `'virtualedit'`.