# How can I get immediately visual feedback on all lines in Vim Visual-Block Insert Mode?

Tags: vim

when I need to insert some same text in several lines, normally I would switch to `VISUAL-BLOCK` and insert the desired text. (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, motions, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>) but as in the default behavior of vim, It only give the first line of visual feedback before returning to `NORMAL` mode (as in the second image). Is there any option or way I could achieve the result as stated in the title of this question?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vim: insert the same characters across multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549729/vim-insert-the-same-characters-across-multiple-lines)

Comment: You could try the plugin [vim-multiple-cursors](https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you feel you need to stay in visual-block mode; you could accomplish this in normal mode in multiple ways.

Label all the lines you need as `0    NULL`, and then use visual-block mode to highlight the column of zeros; then, use `g<C-a>` to increment each line.

You could also use a `:global` command like `:g/\v^\d+/normal A<Tab>NULL`.

There's probably also a solution with a macro, but you see where I'm going with this. It's an easily-scriptable task.

Answer (score 1):

Insert the first null with `A + literal tab + NULL` like this:

```
ID  MEMBER_TYP
--------------
1   NULL
2
3
```

If you are using relative number:

```
:4,+14 normal .
```

More about **Relative Numbers**: If you are at the line 4 and the last relative number shows 13 you can type:

```
14:   ..................... shortcut to :.,.+13
```

After typing `14:` just type `norm .` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Starting from next line until the end:

```
:+1,$ norm .
```

A third way:

```
:.,$s/\v\d+/&   NULL
```

NOTE: Again the tab must be typed literally

```
:.,$ ..................... from this line to the end
\v ....................... very magic
\d+ ...................... match digits
& ........................ matched pattern
```

Maybe the best way:

```
ID  MEMBER_TYP
--------------
1
2
3
```

At the first number, `1`

```
Ctrl-v ........... start visual block
} ................ extends selection till the end
A ................ starts insert at the end of line
<TAB> ............ literal tab
```

Comment: You might want `normal!` unless youre using tpope’s repeat.