# Vim: Insert at same column across multiple lines

Tags: visual-studio-code, vim

For example, this is your starting code:

```
.pt-1 {padding-top: 1px}
.pt-2 {padding-top: 2px}
.pt-3 {padding-top: 3px}
.pt-4 {padding-top: 4px}
.pt-5 {padding-top: 5px}
```

You want to change every number from n to n0 (eg., 1px -> 10px).
The result should be like this:

```
.pt-1 {padding-top: 10px}
.pt-2 {padding-top: 20px}
.pt-3 {padding-top: 30px}
.pt-4 {padding-top: 40px}
.pt-5 {padding-top: 50px}
```

I'm used to VS Code where normally you can just place multiple cursors and type everything all at the same time using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd> and <kbd>Down Arrow</kbd>.

How would you do this in Vim?

**NOTE**:
This is **NOT** this question: [Vim: insert the same characters across multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549729/vim-insert-the-same-characters-across-multiple-lines) (but I wish it was...)

I'm asking how to do this in the same location in multiple lines, that question is saying for the beginning of the lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### With visual-block mode

1. Move the cursor to `1px`.
2. Enter visual-block mode:

   ```
   <C-v>
   ```

   See `:help visual-mode`.
3. Extend the block to `5px`:

   ```
   <Down><Down><Down><Down>
   ```

   or:

   ```
   jjjj
   ```

   or:

   ```
   /5p<CR>
   ```

   or whatever feels intuitive to you.

   See `:help motion.txt` for some inspiration.
4. Append a zero:

   ```
   A0<Esc>
   ```

   See `:help v_b_A`.

### With a substitution

1. Visually select the lines.

   You can use any of the three visual modes, it doesn't matter.
2. Run a substitution on the selection:

   ```
   :'<,'>s/px/0&<CR>
   ```

   Breakdown:

   - `'<,'>` is the range on which the command that follows will operate. This one represents the visual selection, it is automatically inserted for you when you press `:` while in visual mode. See `:help :range`.
   - `s/pattern/replacement` is the substitution command. See `:help :s`.
   - `px` is our pattern.
   - `0&` is the replacement, where `&` represents the whole match. Here, we replace `px` with `0px`. See `:help s/\e`.

### With search and the dot command

1. Jump to the first `px`:

   ```
   /px<CR>
   ```
2. Change the match to `0px`:

   ```
   cgn0px<Esc>
   ```
3. Jump to next match:

   ```
   n
   ```
4. Repeat the change:

   ```
   .
   ```
5. Repeat steps 3-4 as many times as needed.

See `:help gn` and `:help .`.

Comment: PERFECT! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Use the substitute command. You can anchor it on the `px`:

```
:%s/px/0px/
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I mapped <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> to add cursor below and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> to add cursor above in normal mode. (I assume you are using the [VSCodeVim](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim) extension)

1. Open Command Palette and run "Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)" to open `keybindings.json`.
2. Add the following objects at the end of the array:

```json
  {
    "key": "ctrl+alt+j",
    "command": "editor.action.insertCursorBelow",
    "when": "vim.active && editorTextFocus"
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+alt+k",
    "command": "editor.action.insertCursorAbove",
    "when": "vim.active && editorTextFocus"
  }
```

3. Open Keyboard Shortcuts with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>. Search for `ctrl + alt + j` and `ctrl + alt + k` and delete any keybindings that conflict with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>.

Results:

[image: Results]